# Parsing Dart | ANTLR | Handle a comma at the end of parameter list

Tags: parsing, dart, antlr4, grammar, lexer

My apologies for the bad title, but couldn't express it in better words.

I'm writing a parser using ANTLR to calculate complexities in dart code.
Things seem to work fine until I tried to parse a file with the following Method Signature

```
Stream<SomeState> mapEventToState(SomeEvent event,) async* { 
     //someCode to map the State to Event
}
```

Here the `mapEventToState(SomeEvent event,)` creates an issue because of the COMMA `,` at the end.
It presents 2 params to me because of the trailing COMMA (whereas in reality it's just one) and includes some part of the code in the params list thus making the rest of the code unreadable for ANTLR.
This is normal in flutter to end a list of parameters with a COMMA.

The grammar corresponding to it is:

```
initializedVariableDeclaration
  : declaredIdentifier ('=' expression)? (','initializedIdentifier)*
  ;
initializedIdentifier
  : identifier ('=' expression)?
  ;
initializedIdentifierList
  : initializedIdentifier  (',' initializedIdentifier)*
  ;
```

The full grammar can be checked at https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/dart2/Dart2.g4

What should I change on the grammar so that I don't face this issue and the parser can understand that `functionName(Param param1, Param param2,)` is same as `functionName(Param param1, Param param2)`

Answer (score 3):

The Dart project maintains a reference [ANTLR grammar](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/tools/spec_parser/Dart.g#L659) for the Dart language (mostly as a tool for ourselves, to ensure new language features *can* be parsed).
It might be useful as a reference.

The "dart2" grammar you are linking to in the ANTLR repository is probably severely outdated. It was not created by a Dart team member, and if it doesn't handle trailing commas in argument lists, it was probably never complete for Dart 2.0. Use with caution.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that the rule you mentioned (`initializedVariableDeclaration`) is the grammar corresponding to the problem.  That's for an ordinary variable declaration (with an initializer).

I believe you actually want to change `formalParameterList`.  The Dart grammar is provided by [the language specification](https://dart.dev/guides/language/spec), and we can compare the grammar listed there to the grammar from the ANTLR repository.

The ANTLR file has:

```
formalParameterList
  : '(' ')'
  | '(' normalFormalParameters ')'
...
```

whereas the Dart 2.10 specification has, from section 9.2 (Formal Parameters):

```
<formalParameterList> ::= ‘(’ ‘)’
| ‘(’ <normalFormalParameters> ‘,’? ‘)’
...
```

You should file an issue against ANTLR or create a pull request to fix it.

That file also does not appear to have been substantially updated since May 2019 and seems to be missing some notable changes to the Dart language since that time (e.g. spread collections (`spreadElement`), collection-if (`ifElement`), and collection-for (`forElement`) from Dart 2.3, and the changes for null safety).